# Write multiple variables of different types to text file

Tags: python, text, save, output

I have a Python code that generates multiple variables which have different types and lengths. I would like to write everything to a txt.

All the variables I want to save are within a `dic` variable called `dicvariable`. 
To be more exact the variables I am trying to save are:

```
dicvariable[0]['VarA'] # variable type int
dicvariable[0]['VarB'] # variable type str
dicvariable[0]['VarC'] # variable type bool
dicvariable[0]['VarD'] # variable type NoneType
dicvariable[0]['VarE'] # variable type list (size can be anything)
dicvariable[0]['VarF'] # variable type dict (itself contains 5 more variables type ndarray)
```

The first thing I do is to extract the variables one by one from `dicvariable:`

```
VarA = dicvariable[0]['VarA'] # variable type int
VarB = dicvariable[0]['VarB'] # variable type str
VarC = dicvariable[0]['VarC'] # variable type bool
VarD = dicvariable[0]['VarD'] # variable type NoneType
VarE = dicvariable[0]['VarE'] # variable type list
VarF1 = dicvariable[0]['VarF']['VarF1'] # variable type nparray (any size)
VarF2 = dicvariable[0]['VarF']['VarF2'] # variable type nparray (any size)
VarF3 = dicvariable[0]['VarF']['VarF3'] # variable type nparray (any size)
VarF4 = dicvariable[0]['VarF']['VarF4'] # variable type nparray (any size)
VarF5 = dicvariable[0]['VarF']['VarF5'] # variable type nparray (any size)
```

Now I want to open a txt file, and save there all these variables, preferably in a way in I can later easily load the txt in other programs such as matlab. 
Also the original dic variables has `nobs` entries (i.e. `dicvariable[0], dicvariable[1], (...), divariable(nobs)`), so I would like to repeat this process and save `nobs` txt files.

EDIT:

Here's what I tried which yielded an error:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'w')
f.write(VarA + '\n' )
f.write(VarB + '\n' )
f.write(VarC + '\n' )
f.write(VarD + '\n' )
f.write(VarE + '\n' )
f.write(VarF1 + '\n' )
f.write(VarF2 + '\n' )
f.write(VarF3 + '\n' )
f.write(VarF4 + '\n' )
f.write(VarF5 + '\n' )
f.close()
```

Comment: And what is the exact problem?

Comment: Alright, I have added what I have tried which did not work. 
I actually searched a bit on how to do this but still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Show the error as well please. I think you just missed to convert your variables to strings first: `f.write(str(VarA) + '\n' )`

Comment: Alright! Thanks. Seems to be working now!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that those variables are not text data.  You need to convert them to text before you can write them to to a text file.  The normal way to do this is with `str(myvar)`.  So you could do `f.write(str(VarF1) + '\n' )`.  You can do it in a loop like so:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for subdict in dictvariable:
        for value in subdict.values():
            if not hasattr(value, 'values'):
                f.write(str(value)+'\n')
                continue
            for subvalue in value.values():
                f.write(str(subvalue)+'\n')
```

This could be simplified using a generator:

```
def getvars(data):            
    for subdata in data:
        for value in subdata.values():
            if not hasattr(value, 'values'):
                yield value
                continue
            for subvalue in value.values():
                yield subvalue

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(str(value)+'\n' for value in getvars(dictvariable))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the shelve module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html

This will save all your variables into a dictionary in a binary file, IIRC. It is useful for saving the settings of a program.

Here's a simple intro: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter8/ Go to the section: Saving Variables with the shelve Module

Comment: Shelve files can't be imported into other programming languages.